# How do I call a generic static method thats in the main class from the main method?

Tags: java

For example In my main class I have

```
public class main 
{

    // main method 
    public static <T extends Building<T>> T houseAll(T input)
    {
        // random information

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       // This is where I will make the call
    }

}
```

So how would I make the call in the main method from a generic static method thats in the main class?

Comment: Would you please be so kind and include the skeleton of  `Building`?

Comment: main.<Building>houseAll(new Building());

Comment: This is confusing because you have a class named `main`, a method called `main`, and another method (`houseAll`) with a comment noting it is the main method.

Answer (score -1):

What wrong using:

```
public class main {

    // main method
    public static <T extends Building<T>> T houseAll(T input) {
        // random information
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is where I will make the call
        houseAll(null);
    }

}
```